# .NET API to run powershell scripts

Tags: c#, .net, api, rest, powershell

I am not sure how to approach on this , I am looking for any reference or hint to create REST API using C#.NET that will run power shell script saved in .PS1 file and return Json media type. I have limited experience with API with data model. but Since this one won't have model I am lost. Especially for Collection of objects. I need to run script and return the shell output in Json format. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to invoke powershell from a c# program.  [This MSDN link](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/kebab/2014/04/28/executing-powershell-scripts-from-c/) describes ways to do that.  The important functionality come from the System.Management.Automation library.  Here is some sample code, copied from that article:

```
using (PowerShell PowerShellInstance = PowerShell.Create())
{
    // use "AddScript" to add the contents of a script file to the end of the execution pipeline.
    // use "AddCommand" to add individual commands/cmdlets to the end of the execution pipeline.
    PowerShellInstance.AddScript("param($param1) $d = get-date; $s = 'test string value'; " +
            "$d; $s; $param1; get-service");

    // use "AddParameter" to add a single parameter to the last command/script on the pipeline.
    PowerShellInstance.AddParameter("param1", "parameter 1 value!");
```

// invoke execution on the pipeline (ignore output)
    PowerShellInstance.Invoke();
    }

Read the article for more details.

Comment: Perfect!! Thank you. This is exactly what i was looking for

Comment: "Here is some more text because StackOverflow wants more than 30 for a post." - ha ha!

Comment: Link is not working anymore - 404